# Why doesn't pandas dataframe need full row values?

Tags: pandas

```
fields = ['name', 'type', 'age']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=fields)

item1 = {'name': 'john', type:'student', 'age': 21}
item2 = {'name': 'john',  'age': 21}

for item in items:
   df = df.append(item, ignore_index=True)
```

I had thought only 'item1' would be able to be appended, not 'item2' since it has only 2 required fields. Is this normal?

Comment: It is normal ...

Comment: Missing values are allowed!